# Evaluate a limit at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the following limit without Lospital rule nor series
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{a^n}+\frac{1}{b^n}+\frac{1}{c^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
I tried to take log to both sides to be 
$$\ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left((ab)^n +(bc)^n+(ac)^n\right)}{n}-\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{n\ln(abc)}{n}$$ 
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left((ab)^n +(bc)^n+(ac)^n\right)}{n}-\ln(abc)$$
But i could not solve the first limit? $$0<a<b<c$$

Comment: Something is not right.

Comment: $n\to \infty$ ??

Comment: Surely all of the terms are constant with respect to $x$ and the limit is $$ \left(\frac{1}{a^n} + \frac{1}{b^n} + \frac{1}{c^n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}, $$ *n'est-ce pas*?

Comment: The limit is w.r.t x Iam sorry

Comment: Tell us where $a,b,c$ live please

Comment: @HussienMohamed If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: In fact i try to understand the answers @gimusi

Comment: @HussienMohamed Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $0<a<b<c$, than we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{a^n}+\frac{1}{b^n}+\frac{1}{c^n}}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{a^n}}=\frac{1}{a}
$$

Comment: If $0<a<b<c<1$ the result is not the inverse of the less but the inverse of the greatest. Can you see why?

Comment: @samjoe: Sorry! You  are right and I made a stupid mistake ! I edit..:)

Comment: This clearly is simplest approach!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's mathematically right but if you take the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{a^n}+\frac{1}{b^n}+\frac{1}{c^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And put the terms on the same denominator

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{(bc)^n+(ac)^n+(ab)^n}{(abc)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{abc} \lim_{n\to \infty}\left((bc)^n+(ac)^n+(ab)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
This limit doesn't diverge becuase what is inside the limit is (I think) smaller or equal than $$ bc  + ac+ ab$$ So a upper bound of the limit is $$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$$
Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I think what inside is not smaller than or equall $$bc+ac+ab$$nut also iam not sure  @WarreG

Comment: It's true for $n=1$ and for $n=2$ it's pretty much $$ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \leqslant  a+b$$ and that is also true. That was my reasoning, you might be able to prove it by induction but that would bring it too far.

Comment: Nope, I'm wrong.You need to have more information about a b and c.

Comment: I have mentioned informations about a , b and c

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b,c>0$ and wlog $\frac1a=max\{\frac1a,\frac1b\frac1c\}$ thus

$$\left(\frac{1}{a^n}+\frac{1}{b^n}+\frac{1}{c^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{\log{\left(\frac{1}{a^n}+\frac{1}{b^n}+\frac{1}{c^n}\right)}}{n}}=e^{\frac{\log{\left(\frac{1}{a^n}\right)}+\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}}{n}}\to\frac1a$$

indeed

$$\frac{\log{\left(\frac{1}{a^n}\right)}+\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}}{n}=\frac{n\log{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}+\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}}{n}=$$
$$=\log{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}+\frac{\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}}{n}\to \log{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}+0=\log{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)}$$

Comment: How the second limit in the last row tends to 0 ? @gimusi

Comment: Since $0\leq\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}\leq\log 3$ then $$\frac{\log{\left(1+\frac{a^n}{b^n}+\frac{a^n}{c^n}\right)}}{n}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a,b,c>0.$ Let $M= \max (a,b,c).$ Then

$$M = (M^n)^{1/n} < (a^n+b^n + c^n)^{1/n} \le (3M^n)^{1/n} = 3^{1/n}M.$$

Since $3^{1/n} \to 1,$ we see $(a^n+b^n + c^n)^{1/n} \to M.$ The answer for the problem as stated is therefore $\max (1/a,1/b,1/c).$